# Why exec() assigns different id against under -5 on python?

Tags: python, exec

This is python code.

```
for e in range(-10, 10):
    exec('x=%d'% e)
    exec('y=%d'% e)
    print e, id(x), id(y), x is y
```

I expected the print statement shows only Trues.
But it is not. under -5, that shows False.

Result is

```
-10 38832080 38832056 False
-9 38832032 38832080 False
-8 38832056 38832032 False
-7 38832080 38832056 False
-6 38832032 38832080 False
-5 30857416 30857416 True
-4 30857392 30857392 True
-3 30857368 30857368 True
-2 30857344 30857344 True
-1 30857320 30857320 True
0 30857296 30857296 True
1 30857272 30857272 True
2 30857248 30857248 True
3 30857224 30857224 True
4 30857200 30857200 True
5 30857176 30857176 True
6 30857152 30857152 True
7 30857128 30857128 True
8 30857104 30857104 True
9 30857080 30857080 True
```

Why exec assigns different id to x and y respectively under -5?

Comment: I really hope this is just a dark-corner curiosity, and that you aren't using exec this way, or "is" like this in real code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CPython caches small integers between -5 and 256. See [PyInt_FromLong](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#PyInt_FromLong):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

Comment: Thanks you. I got the point :) 
Anyway, is there any reason that the range is between -5 and 256?

Answer (score 1):

This is a cpython implementation detail.  You should use `==` to check if integers are the same.  The surprising thing is that cpython actually returns `True` for some integers:

```
x = -5
y = -5
print x is y  #suprisingly prints `True` with cpython
```

This is because cpython "interns" small integers for efficiency -- It can do that because integers are immutable types.  It does the same thing with strings as well.